# Setting the value of the PublishingFieldImage

Tags: 2013, javascript, publishing, sharepoint-on-prem

I want to insert a image from another media resource. This will be uploaded into the site assets folder (or a defined one).

These selection will be made in a app part, that will be opened up in a modal dialog. After the dialog closes, it returns the url, where the image is stored like

```
"http://spdomain/siteassets/myimage.png".
```

Now I would store these image into the `PublishingFieldImage` Column, the best case is, that it will be done in JavaScript.

Is that possible? Or is there another solution (instead of programming a core solution that works with C#)?

Answer (score 1):

Publishing Image field accepts the value in the following format:

```
<img src='{imageurl}'>
```

The following example demonstrates how to set Publishing Image field value via JSOM.

```
var listTitle = 'Pages';
var itemId = 1;
var fieldName = 'PublishingRollupImage';
var imageUrl = '/PublishingImages/NewsDetails.png';
var fieldValue = String.format("<img src='{0}'  >",imageUrl);

updateListItem(listTitle,itemId,fieldName,fieldValue, 
   function(){
       console.log('List item has been updated');
   },
   function(sendera,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
   });
```

where

```
function updateListItem(listTitle,itemId,fieldName,fieldValue,success,error)
{
   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
   var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   item.set_item(fieldName, fieldValue);
   item.update();
   ctx.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
            success();
      },
      error);
}
```